# View MPEG-TS stream in browser

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create a webpage with a video player that can play a H264 mpeg-ts live stream. I can't find any web player that can do that.

I read that JWPlayer is capable of doing that, but only in the paid version.

The stream can be played in VLC and any other players.

What can I do? I tried using ffmpeg to convert the stream to something more useful, but no succes.

```
ffmpeg -i "http://localhost:9002/tv.ts" -vcodec libx264 -r 20 -s 320x240 -threads 2 -vprofile baseline -vpre zoom -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 96000 -ar 48000 -ac 1 -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.0.28:1935/live/_definst_/c3
```

This is what I get:

```
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0xbb9500] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xbb9500] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0xbaa6e0] decoding for stream 1 failed
[mpegts @ 0xbaa6e0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://192.168.0.28:9002/tv.ts':
  Duration: N/A, start: 30764.854700, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x44](???): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x45]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
File for preset 'zoom' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to include hls.js player in your website. This player transmuxes your TS stream into MP4 fragments in order to be played in any browser. It is free and easily integrated.

Demo page https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/

Github page https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/